# Console script to constantly click button

Tags: javascript, html, console

Say I visit a webpage which has the following line of code:

```
<a class="btn">Example</a>
```

I need a Javascript code which I could run in the Google Chrome console to constantly click that element until it's not present on the page anymore.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

window.setInterval(function() { 
     btn.click();
}, 30); /// time in milliseconds`

Comment: thanks @Konrud that is what I want, but it only presses the button once

Comment: Nope, it presses each 30 milliseconds.

Comment: @Konrud I don't think it does.... the button is only pressed once and then the console says `XHR finished loading: POST`

Comment: The way you display it it doesn't have any `href` attribute so I don't really know what it does when it's clicked.

Comment: @Konrud I believe it's a pagination script and when the button is clicked, it displays the next set of data and so on